# Drilling a hole in a tree branch - where should you do it?

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]

As shown in the picture, where should you drill it such that the branch is minimally damaged and maximally damaged and why?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. If the answer by Farcher is too biological, since you said the question could also be about a thick rod, then why did you ask about a tree branch?

Answer (score 1):

This is in part a question about Biology.

The structure of a trunk and a branch is shown below.

[image]

Drilling holes $A$ and $C$ will impact on the growth and health of the branch more than drilling hole $B$ because more of the growth and transportation part of the tree is affected.

Drilling hole $A$ might well weaken the branch as this is equivalent to cutting a knick in a branch to facilitate bending and breaking the branch.
On the other had depending on the diameter of the branch and the drill drilling hole $B$ could weaken the branch because of the loss of the loss of the strong central part (heartwood).
Drilling hole $C$ would not be a good idea of the object going trough the hole is needed to support a structure.

I think you are left with hole $A$ which causes more damage to the growth and life of the branch and possibly reduces the strength of the rest of the branch and hole $B$ which affects less of the growth of the branch but impacts on a greater part of the branch.

What is important is to prevent diseases and insects going inside the branch once the outer layer (bark) has been penetrated.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer from a biology point of view, but this is really a physics question, the tree might as well have been a thick rod

Comment: @JerryCohen I did my best but it was not clear from your question as to the purpose of drilling a hole.  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

A strange question since drilling a hole in a tree is going to damage the tree no matter where you drill it.

If this is in a physics/engineering context, my guess is you are supposed to treat the tree branch as a [cantilever beam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantilever) and think about where it is in tension and where it is in compression.